# Fitting a time-varying coefficient model in python

Tags: python, time-varying-covariate

I have some data that varies with time and some that stays constant (e.g., location, race stay constant).  Is it possible to implement a **mixed** time-varying coefficient model in python?  What I mean is:

$$
y = \beta_0(t) \cdot x_0 + \beta_1(t) \cdot x_1 + \beta_2 \cdot x_3 + \beta_3
$$

where $\beta_0, \beta_1$ are time-varying (dependent on $t$), and the rest of the betas are not.

This is similar to the SAS package TVEM (page 7, eq. 4 of [this doc](https://methodology.psu.edu/sites/default/files/software/tvem/TVEM_3.1.0.pdf)).

It seems this might be possible in R using the `gam` models, but I'm not very familiar with R.  Any clues to approach this in python (or get me started) would be helpful.  I'm familiar with the `statsmodels` package and the `scipy` stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Cross Validated!

One way to fit such a model is to use Kalman filter. It is not an out-of-the-box experience, but it works. I used `pykalman` package, which is very nice, but is no longer maintained (or it seems so from it's github repository). I saw that `statsmodels` also has a Kalman filter implementation, it may do the job as well.

To fit the time varying coefficients (using `pykalman` notation from https://pykalman.github.io/#mathematical-formulation), put your $\beta_i$'s into $A_t$ and adjust their change rate by choosing appropriate value of $Q$. You may want to use diagonal $Q$ with zeroes for fixed coefficients, and positive values for larger ones. You can use MLE (or grid search, or random search), to find the best ones.

Values of $x_i$ go into $C_t$ and values of $y$ into $y_t$.